# FIWARE OPC-UA. Add source timestamp to metadata

Tags: iot, fiware, opc-ua

I use the fiware iot-agent opc-ua https://github.com/Engineering-Research-and-Development/iotagent-opcua. How can I get the sorce timestamp of an monitored item from the opc-ua server and add it to the metadata? many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the last release of the OPC UA Agent! It should satisfy your requirement :-) 
In the last version, the OPC UA Agent gets OPC UA source and server timestamps (if exist) and sends both as metadata to the Orion Context Broker. You don't need to configure anything to enable that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25875593)

Comment: The post provided an implicit answer. Anyway, I edited the post and detailed in-depth. Thanks for your feedback